# Send a parameter from bash to a python script

Tags: python, bash, jenkins, boto3

I'm trying to send a parameter on jenkins and have the parameter recognized on the a python file.

Is there a command where I could do this on bash:

```
param = "Hello World"
param -> /usr/green/test.py
```

Also how does the py file know to grab the parameter?

Answer (score 4):

you can pass parameters from BASH to you python script via using **sys** egg in the python scripts. then pass on the environment variables in the command .

**PyScript**

```
import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

**command in BASH :**

```
$python test.py $BUILD_ID $BUILD_URL
```

**output :**

```
Number of arguments: 2 arguments.
Argument List: ['test.py', '107', 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/artefact/builds/24']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access parameters passed to the script this way:

```
import sys

print sys.argv[1]

~ python test.py 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to print the parameter and process through a pipe with python.

Like:

read.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

pythonparams = sys.stdin.read()

# do something
```

then

```
echo "$param"|./read.py
```

Comment: I hereby nominate this answer for the Rube Goldberg Award xD

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the script's arguments after the file path separated by spaces, like this:

```
/usr/green/test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

to pass the value of a bash variable to the script, you have to prefix the variable name with a `$` (dollar sign):

```
param="Hello world"
/usr/green/test.py "$param"
```

The list of arguments in the python script can be accessed with `sys.argv`. The first element in the list is the path to the script therefore the second element is the first argument.

**Example**
/usr/green/test.py (Python 3):

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
```

bash input:

```
param="Hello World"
python3 /usr/green/test.py "$param"
```

bash output:

```
Hello World
```

Note: You have to put the variable name in quotes or Hello and World will be passed as two separate arguments to test.py.

To execute the script without the `python` command, you can add a `#!` (shebang) line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
```

Make the script executable by typing in bash:

```
chmod +x /usr/green/test.py
```